# Can't Load Custom Theme

Tags: themes

I am currently using Zenburn.  My `.emacs` file contains

```
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/"))

(add-to-list 'custom-theme-load-path "~/.emacs.d/themes/")
(load-theme 'zenburn t)
```

I want to use `tomorrow-night-bright`.  So, I placed the `tomorrow-night-bright.el` file in the same folder with `zenburn.el`.  When I try

```
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/"))

(add-to-list 'custom-theme-load-path "~/.emacs.d/themes/")
(load-theme 'tomorrow-night-bright t)
```

Emacs says it can't find the file/folder.  When I use `M-x customize-themes`, it has it listed, but again can't find it when I try to execute it.

Answer (score 1):

#### Investigation

You're working with this [tomorrow-night-bright.el file](https://github.com/chriskempson/tomorrow-theme/blob/master/GNU%20Emacs/tomorrow-night-bright-theme.el), right? Here's the entirety of it:

```
(require 'color-theme-tomorrow)
(color-theme-tomorrow--define-theme night-bright)
```

It seems like that theme is organized a little bit differently from others. Let's compare it to Zenburn, the one that's currently working from your init file. [Zenburn's file](https://github.com/bbatsov/zenburn-emacs/blob/master/zenburn-theme.el) ends with

```
(provide-theme 'zenburn)
```

This lets you call `(load-theme 'zenburn t)` and have it work. Note that tomorrow-night-bright.el never calls `provide-theme`. So we can't just call `load-theme` on it. We have to find the location of the function `color-theme-tomorrow--define-theme`, and add it to our load path. By poking around the github repository, I [found it here](https://github.com/chriskempson/tomorrow-theme/blob/master/GNU%20Emacs/color-theme-tomorrow.el#L535).

#### Fix

So, if we can't just call `load-theme`, what do we need to do? If you download the two files from the tomorrow-theme repository, put them on your load path. Then, you should be able to call this code:

```
(load "/path/to/tomorrow-night-bright-theme.el")
(load-theme 'tomorrow-night-bright t)
```

The first line will create the theme; the second one loads it.

#### Simpler alternative

Steve Purcell wrote a version of the tomorrow-night themes with "much more extensive face definitions" [here](https://github.com/purcell/color-theme-sanityinc-tomorrow). If you download one of those files (or [install it from melpa](http://melpa.org/#/color-theme-sanityinc-tomorrow)), you should be able to just call `load-theme` on it.

Comment: I want to try the simpler alternative.  I installed it with Melpa and put the el file in my themes folder.  I can use M-x customize-themes and get it to work.  But, when I add (load-theme 'sanityinc-tomorrow-bright t), it says it can't find the file.